# How to trigger a fail in Travis CI?

Tags: bash, travis-ci

One of my test is a simple bash command with an `if` condition. I want Travis CI to consider a build as failed if the condition is positive.

I try to do it this way (a part of the `.travis.yml` file):

```
# ...

script:
    - npm run build
    - if [[ `git status --porcelain` ]]; then >&2 echo "Fail"; fi

# ...
```

But when the condition is positive, the message is just printed and the build is considered as successful.

What should I do to make a build failed when the condition is positive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `exit 1;` after the `echo`. [More info](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals).

Comment: Would use `false` to get the return status. There might be some tearing down bypassed if you call `exit`.
If you really want to stop the script right now, call `travis_terminate 1`.

Comment: @joepd Could you please give a full example of a command which uses `false` instead of `exit`?

Comment: @joepd I've used Travis for some years and Bash for over a decade, and I have no idea what you mean. If there's any teardown to do it should be done in an exit trap. It's not like I'm saying you should `kill -9` ([which you really should never do](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#I.27m_trying_to_kill_-9_my_job_but_blah_blah_blah...))

Comment: I used `exit 1;` and discovered that it causes after_script to be bypassed, which it's not normally for a failing build.

Comment: As @DannyTuppeny pointed out, `exit` will give you problems if you rely on some post script phase. `return` worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/61588532/239408

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to assert a condition but continue with testing, the following worked for me:

`` bash -c 'if [[ `git status --porcelain` ]]; then >&2 echo "Fail"; exit 1; fi' ``

This will make the build results fail but not terminate it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `return 1;`

[Travis compiles the different commands into a single bash script](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/job-lifecycle/#how-does-this-work-or-why-you-should-not-use-exit-in-build-steps) so `exit 1` or `travis_terminate 1` will abruptly interrupt the workflow and skip the `after_script` phase.

For complex commands that you want to make more readable and don't want to move to their own script, [you can take advantage of YAML's literal scalar indicator](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/bash-logic-structures-and-conditionals-if-case-loops-etc-travis-c):

```
script:
    - |
      if [[ `git status --porcelain` ]]; then 
        >&2 echo "Fail"
        return 1
      fi
```